# Did Krishna marry Rukmini against her parents wish?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, dharma

I clearly know that Rukmini and Krishna married each other with mutual agreement/wish.

But my doubt is whether the marriage happened against the wish of Rukmini's mother/ father/ siblings or all?

I allegedly know that Rukmini has to actually marry Sisupala according to their parent's wish. But Krishna eloped her with her wish.

But if it is true that Krishna married Rukmini against her parent's wish, is it allowed to do? If the girl accepts to marry, then the partner can elope her even though her parents disagree their marriage?

Or is there any special context for Krishna that allows him to do like that?

Comment: Yes there is a love letter describing her situation mentioned in shrimad bhagwata I will post the letter

Comment: See this answer parents were not against marriage but Rukmi her brother was they were even considering this marriage http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/286/why-did-lord-krishna-kidnap-rukmini-to-get-married/333#333

Comment: Her parents were not opposed to the match - only her brother Rukmi who held sway in the family decision-making.